# Why does [5,6,8,7][1,2] = 8 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I can't wrap my mind around this quirk.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6][1,2,3]; // 4
[1,2,3,4,5,6][1,2]; // 3
```

I know `[1,2,3] + [1,2] = "1,2,31,2"`, but I can't find what type or operation is being performed.

Answer (score 389, accepted):

```js
[1,2,3,4,5,6][1,2,3];
      ^         ^
      |         |
    array       + — array subscript access operation,
                    where index is `1,2,3`,
                    which is an expression that evaluates to `3`.
```

The second `[...]` cannot be an array, so it’s an array subscript operation. And the contents of a subscript operation are not a delimited list of operands, but a single expression.

Read more about the comma operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: correct.. last index used.. more examples:
[1,2,3,4,5,6][1,2,3] === [1,2,3,4,5,6][3];
[1,1,1,5,1,1][3] === [1,1,1,5,1,1][1,2,3];
in this way [1,1,1,5,1,1][3] == 5

Answer (score 110):

Because `(1,2) == 2`.  You've stumbled across the [comma operator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-comma-operator) (or [simpler explanation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)).

Unless commas appear in a declaration list, parameter list, object or array literal, they act like any other binary operator.  `x, y` evaluates `x`, then evaluates `y` and yields that as the result.

Answer (score 21):

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6][1,2,3];
```

Here the second box i.e. `[1,2,3]` becomes `[3]` i.e. the last item so the result will be 4
for example if you keep `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` in an array

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6];

arr[3]; // as [1,2,3] in the place of index is equal to [3]
```

similarly

```
*var arr2=[1,2,3,4,5,6];

 // arr[1,2] or arr[2] will give 3*
```

But when you place a + operator in between then the second square bracket is not for mentioning index. It is rather another array
That's why you get

```
[1,2,3] + [1,2] = 1,2,31,2
```

i.e.

```
var arr_1=[1,2,3];

var arr_2=[1,2];

arr_1 + arr_2; // i.e.  1,2,31,2
```

Basically in the first case it is used as index of array and in the second case it is itself an array.