# javascript (x, y, z) + a means what

Tags: javascript

I just saw a expression from a JavaScript sample like following:

```
  var some = (x, y, z) + a;
```

what does it mean? and what is the result?

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421013/why-does-5-6-8-71-2-8-in-javascript/7421030#7421030

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is JavaScript's [**comma operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

```
x, y, z; // is the same as
x;
y;
z; // this is the last thing returned, so
(x, y, z) === z;
```

Therefore, `var some = (x, y, z) + a;` is the same as `var some = z + a;`, except `x` and `y` are evaluated too.

It is useful if you want to shorten things to one line or need something evaluated before a second thing is available.

Comment: can u tell what is the purpose of x and y??is it same as *var x,y;* and *var some=z+a;*

Comment: @ArunKillu `x` and `y` do not get `var`d, they just get evaluated. You'd normally use an expression rather than just an `x` or `y`, e.g. you invoke a function `setZ()` or do some operator `--z` instead of simply an "`x`".

Comment: @PaulS. yes i got it .i know the use of comma operators in loops and function ,this was a new information.+1

Answer (score 0):

below example shows your solution in this, you see it show only last assign value means (x,y,z) it take only z and add it to 'a' and display it.

```
<script>
    x=1;
    y=2;
    z=0;
    a=0;
    var some = (x, y, z) + a;
    alert(some)
</script>
```