# Javascript - Accessing Properties with Comma Between - What does the Programmer Mean?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm modifying a Javascript library which was written by a third party. The code does work for the most part. There are no syntax errors. It will be nearly impossible to ask the author about the code.

I came across this construct, and cannot understand what the programmer intended.

```
pages[uuid, elIndex] = 12;
```

Inspecting with Chrome devtools, I see that page is an object. uuid is a string and elIndex is a number.

I can't understand what's intended here with the comma between multiple object properties. Is this some very obscure Javascript syntax? What is meant by accessing "multiple properties" like this?

Comment: Maybe the programmer thought that this was multidimensional array access. [It isn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20645191/1048572) But without further code, we can only guess either.

Comment: This seems like it would be mistake. What this does is just set both of the properties ("uuid" and "elIndex") to 12. I imagine that setting the uuid to 12 was not intended.

Comment: @AlexBieg no, it only sets `pages[elINdex] = 12`. The comma operator has lower precedence than array acces

Comment: @user3080953 Oops you are correct. I messed up my little test in the console. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user3080953 is correct. When I inspect in Chrome, it's as if the first parameter is ignored. Maybe I should just chalk it up to a sloppy programmer - though the library is pretty well written IMO - not a beginner.

Comment: Considering `pages` is an object and `uuid` and `elIndex` are the Keys of associated array. Effectively it is equivalent to `pages[elIndex]=12`

You can try this:
`var pages = {uuid: "text: uuid", elIndex: "text: elIndex"};
uuid = "uuid"; elIndex="elIndex";
pages[uuid, elIndex] = 12;
console.log(pages);`

Comment: From the names of the variables, pages being a collection of pages, uuid being an id for a page, and elIndex being the index of an element on a certain page, and the attempt to set something to a numeric value (12),  I would guess `pages[uuid][elIndex] = 12` was meant.

Comment: @OmSao your understanding is incorrect, user3080953 explains why.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Consensus seems to be that the programmer was just confused - even though the syntax was used throughout the library. But what's important (to me) is that this is not some super quirky aspect of Javascript (I am unaware of).

Comment: @CharlieDalsass not necessarily, as there are a million different ways for legal syntax snippets to interact oddly and the grammar is complicated enough as it is.

Comment: Agreed this should not raise a Javascript error, now that I understand how "comma operator" works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
pages[uuid, elIndex] = 12;
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
pages[elIndex] = 12;
```

This is the seldom-used [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Unlike a method call (which takes several arguments separated by commas), the array indexer takes a single expression, so `uuid, elIndex` is parsed as a single expression that uses the comma operator. The comma operator evaluates both sides, then throws away the value of the left side and returns the value of the right side. It's occasionally used in `for`-loop initializers, and it's used heavily in minified code, but otherwise it really doesn't have a ton of practical applications if you're trying to write readable code.

As Bergi noted in the comments above, the author probably *thought* this would be a multidimensional array access, but it isn't. It's just `pages[elIndex]`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Great help. This actually looks like a similar one to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645191/undestanding-double-bracket-operation-in-javascript Perhaps the programmer was so familiar with the comma  operator that he threw that in sort of like a "to do", assuming it wouldn't confuse the heck out of other programmers.