# javascript 2 dimensional array does not return the correct value

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm testing out a rock paper scissor lizard spock game. Instead of generating the possible outcomes, I used `var matrix = [ ]` to capture all the possibilities. at array location `matrix[3,0]`, the string entered was "rock wins". However,  I ran `console.log(matrix[3,0])` right after the array and it produced a different result.

can someone tell me why that is?

```
var matrix = [];

matrix[0,0] = "it's a tie";
matrix[0,1] = "Paper wins";
matrix[0,2] = "rock wins";
matrix[0,3] = "rock wins";
matrix[0,4] = "Spock wins";
matrix[1,0] = "Paper wins";
matrix[1,1] = "it's a tie";
matrix[1,2] = "Scissors win";
matrix[1,3] = "Lizard wins";
matrix[1,4] = "Paper wins";
matrix[2,0] = "rock wins";
matrix[2,1] = "Scissors win";
matrix[2,2] = "it's a tie";
matrix[2,3] = "Scissors win";
matrix[2,4] = "spock wins";
matrix[3,0] = "rock wins";

log.console(matrix[3,0]); //returns spock wins
```

Comment: Hard to comment on code we can't see… `matrix[3,0]` doesn't do what you think, try `matrix[3][0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not. It actually returns "rock wins".
In short, you use the incorrect syntax.

### Why does it happen?

You may miss this part and go right to "How should it be?" if you are not interested in understanding the magic behaviour of JavaScript.

1. You have declared a **1-dimensional** array.
2. When you try to assign or read the following property `matrix[0,0]`, `0,0` is recognized **as an expression** which is evaluated to the last number (0 in this case).

It means that

```
matrix[0,0] = "it's a tie";
matrix[0,1] = "Paper wins";
matrix[0,2] = "rock wins";
// ...
matrix[2,3] = "Scissors win";
matrix[2,4] = "spock wins";
matrix[3,0] = "rock wins";
console.log(matrix[3,0]);
```

is the same as

```
matrix[0] = "it's a tie";
matrix[1] = "Paper wins";
matrix[2] = "rock wins";
// ...
matrix[3] = "Scissors win";
matrix[4] = "spock wins";
matrix[0] = "rock wins";
console.log(matrix[0]); // returns "rock wins"
```

Read more about it [in this StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421013/why-does-5-6-8-71-2-8-in-javascript).

The reason of it is that you are using a wrong syntax.

### How should it be?

That's how you access value in multidimensional array in JavaScript:

```
var val = arr[key1][key2][key3]; // not arr[key1, key2, key3]
```

That's how your code should look like:

```js
var matrix = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) matrix[i] = [];

matrix[0][0] = "it's a tie";
matrix[0][1] = "Paper wins";
matrix[0][2] = "rock wins";
// ...
matrix[2][3] = "Scissors win";
matrix[2][4] = "spock wins";
matrix[3][0] = "rock wins";
document.write(matrix[3][0]);  // not matrix[3,0]
```

Another good option is to describe your 2D array this way:

```
var matrix = [
    ["it's a tie", "Paper wins", "rock wins"],
    ["Paper wins", "it's a tie", "Scissors wins"]
    // ...     
];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
matrix[0,0] = "it's a tie";
```

the part in square brackets is an expression that is evaluated and coerced to string. The expression `0,0` returns the value after the last "," and evaluates to `0`, `0,1` evaluates to 1, and so on.

So:

```
var matrix = [];

matrix[0,0] = "it's a tie";
matrix[0,1] = "Paper wins";
matrix[0,2] = "rock wins";
matrix[0,3] = "rock wins";
matrix[0,4] = "Spock wins";
matrix[1,0] = "Paper wins";
matrix[1,1] = "it's a tie";
matrix[1,2] = "Scissors win";
matrix[1,3] = "Lizard wins";
matrix[1,4] = "Paper wins";
matrix[2,0] = "rock wins";
matrix[2,1] = "Scissors win";
matrix[2,2] = "it's a tie";
matrix[2,3] = "Scissors win";
matrix[2,4] = "spock wins";
matrix[3,0] = "rock wins";
```

Creates the "one dimensional" array of the last value assigned to each index:

```
["rock wins", "Scissors win", "it's a tie", "Scissors win", "spock wins"]
```

and

```
matrix[3,0]
```

evaluates to

```
matrix[0]
```

hence you get "rock wins".

What you want is:

```
var matrix = [[],[],[],[]];

matrix[0][0] = "it's a tie";
matrix[0][1] = "Paper wins";
matrix[0][2] = "rock wins";
matrix[0][3] = "rock wins";
matrix[0][4] = "Spock wins";
matrix[1][0] = "Paper wins";
matrix[1][1] = "it's a tie";
matrix[1][2] = "Scissors win";
matrix[1][3] = "Lizard wins";
matrix[1][4] = "Paper wins";
matrix[2][0] = "rock wins";
matrix[2][1] = "Scissors win";
matrix[2][2] = "it's a tie";
matrix[2][3] = "Scissors win";
matrix[2][4] = "spock wins";
matrix[3][0] = "rock wins";

console.log(matrix[3][0]); // rock wins
```

You could also use an array literal:

```
var matrix = [
              ["it's a tie","Paper wins","rock wins","rock wins","Spock wins"],
              ["Paper wins","it's a tie","Scissors win","Lizard wins","Paper wins"],
              ["rock wins","Scissors win","it's a tie","Scissors win","spock wins"],
              ["rock wins"]
             ];
```