# How can I have the real count of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, size

I tried this way, but it returns me the wrong count:

```
myArr = [];
myArr[666] = 'hello there';
console.log(myArr.length); // returns me 667
```

It should be 1. How can I have the good count in the fastest way?

Comment: In js number 0 is like number 1. That's why you get 667.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421013/why-does-5-6-8-71-2-8-in-javascript

Answer (score 17):

> It should be 1.

No, it should be 667, because that's how `length` is defined for standard arrays in JavaScript, which [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). Arrays in JavaScript are *inherently sparse*, meaning they can have holes in them (indexes where no value of any kind is stored).

> How can I have the good count in the fastest way?

The only way is by looping. For instance:

```
var count = 0;
myArr.forEach(function() {
    ++count;
});
console.log(count);
```

...or via `reduce` as in [maček's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31882567/157247). `forEach`, `reduce`, and other such only visit entries that actually exist, so they skip the holes in sparse arrays.

---

I should mention that since IE8 still (sigh) has a fair bit of market share, you need to shim `forEach` and `reduce` and such on it if you want to use them. (Which is easy.)

To do this without any shimming, and only count actual index properties (not other kinds of properties), then loosely:

```
var count = 0, name;
for (name in myArr) {
    if (myArr.hasOwnProperty(name) && /^[0-9]+$/.test(name)) {
        ++count;
    }
}
```

That uses a slightly loose definition of what an index property name is; if you want a robust one, see the "Use for-in correctly" part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Comment: we're on the same page, but a `reduce` is probably a little cleaner

Comment: No prob. +1 for providing extra education.

Comment: If you want a fast way `reduce` is not an option

Comment: @DaveGomez: `reduce` isn't slow. If you're worried about the cost of the function calls, [don't be](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html).

Comment: It's slow and complicated, why don't just use `filter` and strip out all the `undefined` values? Also the `forEach` solution you post is simply horrible for something as simple as this, nothing to say about the `for in` "solution".

Comment: @DaveGomez: Repeating "it's slow" doesn't make it true. `filter`'s not going to be any faster -- my guess would be slower, if anything, on an array of any size, since pushing entries into an array is slower than adding one to a value. Also causes more memory-churn (the temporary array).

Comment: Is true, filter is not gonna be faster but it is a lot cleaner and easier to use. Anyway, this is not even a good way to use JavaScript Arrays.

Comment: `filter()` is not just slower, it's a ridiculous tool to reach for given the requirements. It generates a new array... and you don't need one.

Answer (score 8):

You can count the number of non-undefined properties using a reduce

```
var length = myArr.reduce(function(len) { return len+1; }, 0);
console.log(length); // 1
```

Comment: I wonder what [DaveGomez](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1650483/dave-gomez) finds unreadable about this. This is perfect.

Comment: @canon yeah you gotta take everything with a grain of salt on here. Some people don't know what they're talking about. I don't claim to know everything, but I try to avoid providing answers that lack a degree of certainty.

Answer (score 5):

Because arrays are indexed by 0.  `[0...666]` is 667 items.  If you actually want a count of how many items you have, an array might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```
Object.keys(myArr).length;
```

From the documentation:

> Object.keys returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding
>   to the enumerable properties found directly upon object. The ordering
>   of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the
>   properties of the object manually.

This function is [compatible with IE9+](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.keys). The documentation also contains a funtion that can be added for compatibility in all browsers:

```
if (!Object.keys) Object.keys = function(o) {
  if (o !== Object(o))
    throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on a non-object');
  var k=[],p;
  for (p in o) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,p)) k.push(p);
  return k;
}
```

Comment: Beware that `Object.keys` will also include the names non-index enumerable properties, if any exist.

Comment: Warning: `Object.keys` is not available in IE 8/7/6.

Comment: @gusper: It can be shimmed if you're dealing with obsolete browsers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True, but could be good to know that it will not work by default.

Comment: @gusper I thought I should put is as a possible answer. The full compatibility report can be viewed [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.keys).