# Passing 2 values when accessing value in javascript array `myArray[1,3]`

Tags: javascript, arrays

I realize that this is improper syntax, but why is JavaScript ignoring the first number and giving a response instead of breaking?

```
let myArray = [1,2,3,4]

myArray[0,1] // 2
myArray[1,3] // 4
myArray[3,0] // 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does \[5,6,8,7\]\[1,2\] = 8 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421013/why-does-5-6-8-71-2-8-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not improper syntax.

### That's just the comma operator in action.

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

For instance, `[1,2][1,2]`, perhaps bizarrely enough, will return `undefined`.

Why?

The second `[` is interpreted by the compiler to be the array subscript operator, because JavaScript's semantics don't allow two arrays to be next to each other.

Thus, the second `1,2` must be an expression that evaluates to an index. `1,2` results in the first operand being evaluated, followed by the second, which is what's returned. So it uses index `2`, which of course doesn't exist in that array, and we get `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it is [evaluating the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in each set of square brackets.